# jQuery: hide show more button when no content to load

Tags: html, jquery

I have this button that will hide when no more content to load in review page. The button is working great except that it will still show up even if there are no more data to display. I want it to not show up if there is nothing left to load. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Here is my code

```
  $(document).unbind('click').on('click', ".recentreviews5 .showmore", function () {  
    $('#last').val(parseInt($('#last').val()) + 10)

    $('.hide').each(function () {
        var itmidx = $(this).index();
        if (parseInt(itmidx) < parseInt($('#last').val())) {
                        
            var g = $(this).attr('id')

            $(this).removeClass('recent').removeClass('hide')
            $(this).addClass('recent').addClass('show')
        }
    });

    if ((parseInt($('#last').val()) >= parseInt($('#total').val())) || (parseInt($('#last').val()) < 10)) {
        $(".showmore").css('cssText', 'display:none!important')
    }
   
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you try here `$(".showmore").css('cssText', 'display:none!important')` but you can do `$(".showmore").hide()`

Comment: When you have loaded all of your data, what are the values for last and total when you call .val() from the console?

Comment: @JohnGlenn, the values for the total are 50 and the last values are 4

Comment: Have you added a console log before your display: none command to ensure your code is running? Have you confirmed that $(".showmore") returns your button?

Comment: Yes, I've added console.log to check but not printing anything.  Yeah,  $(".showmore") returning the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to manually set the style. The .css call generally speaking doesn't support `!important`.

```
$(".showmore").attr('style', 'display: none !important')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".showmore").attr('hidden', 'hidden')
```

Comment: this will hide your button, then if you want to show it again just use .removeAttr('hidden')

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This code toggle visibility with display:none / display:block

```
$(".showmore").toggle();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.